# Best airflow stategy for cooling a confined area?

Tags: thermodynamics, cooling

I am working on a machine which has an upper side which processes a product. On the lower side of the machine there are a couple of motors with built in inverters and there is a laser unit. There are two fans which blow air out of the machine they sit opposite each other. The motors are mounted between them. Air can come into the machine from the bottom sides.

My question is this. Wouldn't it be much better to have one fan take air in from outside and another being used for extraction?

I think the present system will just cause the machine to draw up air from the bottom and straight out the fan without cooling the air around the unit. Am I right about that?

Comment: Could you add a drawing of your system? It is hard to visualize the setup based on your description, and this is a non-trivial problem.

Comment: Agree with @TylerOlsen's comment. Note that a fan blowing is more effective than a fan sucking - the velocity of the air is much higher downwind than upwind. But the right answer really depends on the details of the setup that are hard to envisage from your description.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the present system will just cause the machine to draw up air from the bottom and straight out the fan without cooling the air around the unit

Sounds like you need baffles.

Most home gadgets have a pull fan system for things that don't require extensive cooling and a push for things that do. Pop the covers off your computer and you will (probably) see a fan that draws air from inside the case, blows it over the CPU's heatsink and then exhausts outside the case.

A big question is where do you live and what is the ambient condition near the machine. If you are in a cold climate get some ducting to draw in outside air (don't forget filters). If you are in Vegas or Dubai this would be counter-productive, just like if the machine is in a room beside a metalworking furnace.

And yes, drawings will help a lot. Pausing here waiting for drawings and local climate info